# Update UILabel-Subview of MKAnnotationview

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview, reuseidentifier

I have a `MapView` with cluster annotations (ADMapCluster). `I want to show the amount of elements in the Cluster`, therefor I'm **adding a UILabel to the MKAnnotationView** as a Subview.

> My Problem is that when I reuse the MKAnnotationView after zooming or
>   similar actions the UILabel doesn't update the text.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(ADClusterMapView *)mapView viewForClusterAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

MKAnnotationView * pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"ADMapCluster"];
if (!pinView) {
    pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"ADMapCluster"];
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map-markers"];
    UILabel *countLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 5, 25, 20)];
    countLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [countLabel setTag:2];
    countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[(ADClusterAnnotation*)pinView.annotation originalAnnotations] count] ];
    countLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Book" size:10];
    [pinView addSubview:countLabel];

}
else {
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
    [((UILabel*)[pinView viewWithTag:2]) setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[(ADClusterAnnotation*)pinView.annotation originalAnnotations] count] ]];
    [((UILabel*)[pinView viewWithTag:2]) setNeedsDisplay];
}
return pinView;
```

}

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and why the labels don't get updated?

Comment: Are you sure about result of **[(ADClusterAnnotation*)pinView.annotation originalAnnotations] count] ]**..?

Comment: Not an answer but the `setText` line in the `else` part would be so much easier to read, maintain, and (most importantly) to debug if it was split up into multiple statements using local variables to hold refs to the objects that line is accessing.  Then you can easily check if something is nil or some unexpected value.

Comment: @KumarKl Yes, you are totally right. The issue is NOT that the labels are not getting updated. Im getting wrong numbers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmmm.... small mistakes make mad ...